# How to define windows security network credentials in a web java app?

Tags: java, windows, security, networking, credentials

First of all i will describe my problem, i'm making an app that will provide the service to upload pictures into a server folder called "uploadPhotos". my app and the uploadPhotos folder are stored physically in diferent servers, so i need a way to define in my app the windows network security credentials so when i try to upload a photo, the app would connect to the other server with the credentials provided and store the photo in the uploadPhoto folder.

i'm using glassfish 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Morning,

You should use LDAP to connect to the Windows Domain Server.  You can use this to authenticate Active Directory credentials.  One way to do this is to have the Windows Domain Server perform the authenticate for both other servers.  This would maintain credential compatibility between the two.

[a link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19575-01/820-7281/giuvw/index.html)! has a little bit more information.